# Can't use MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat

I'm new to android development. I want to create a music player that functions in a client-server fashion. I'm trying to create the server part for now. I found out that I could achieve this using `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` as it says in the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#kotlin). But when I tried to use it in my project it says `Unresolved reference: MediaBrowserServiceCompat` [image: see here]
Although I've set Android Studio to import needed libraries automatically, I tried importing `android.support.v4.*`, `android.support.*`, `androidx.*` explicitly, hoping it might work but it didn't as it turns out. So I went over to the GitHub repo of [UAMP(Universal Android Music Player)](https://github.com/android/uamp) for some help. I found the statement `import androidx.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat` in [this file](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/MusicService.kt). But I couldn't find any library named so[image: see here]

And why my Manifest says `MediaPlaybackService must extend android.app.service`?[image: see here]

How am I supposed to use it?
Thanks!

Edit: I did a little bit of research and tinkering. I tried changing the service name in my Manifest and the associated class name as well to `MyMediaBrowserServiceCompat` and magically it worked(sort of). So now, my question is, is it normal behavior? Should changing the service name really affect this situation? And if its so, how on Earth it works with different names(something not similar to the class name itself) on other peoples' machines? And secondly, now my code says `There's a cycle in the inheritance hierarchy for this type`[image: see here] I searched the web and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796100/cyclic-inheritance-hierarchy-in-java#13796155). So I know what that message means but I can't figure out how to solve it in this case. And my Manifest still says the same: `MyMediaBrowserServiceCompat must extend android.app.service`[image: see here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is related to the dependency where MediaBrowserService is located. Without seeing the dependencies section in your `build.gradle` it's difficult to know, but the MediaBrowserService is located in `implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'`. Try adding that and you should be able to find it.

A note on the message about `There's a cycle in the inheritance hierarchy for this type`: that's because you're essentially referring to the same class as both the parent and child and that won't work as it'll ask for the parent and just get itself back. The reason for it "working" is because you're now only referring to actual files that can be found since the class `MyMediaBrowserService` exists. You'll need to update your service to actually inherit `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` to get it working, and that should work when you have the dependency for it.

Comment: that's the thing. I mentioned it in the question with a screensnap(the second photo). I can't find anything named `media` in `androidx`.

Comment: it wasn't showing up as a library but I explicitly added it to `build.gradle` and re-synced it, and it works now. I don't know why it wasn't working before when I tried the same. But anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In Android Developer, they don't say that clearly how to implement **MediaBrowserServiceCompat** and **MediaBrowserCompat** in the [Audio app overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app) article(if you are following this article). But you can implement with the code below or update the newest version of this support library in this [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media).

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.media:media:1.3.1"
}
```